# Wordpress: "The link you followed has expired" problem

Tags: wordpress, plugins, import

**Hello**,

The problem I am having is a very general problem when it comes to importing/uploading your plugins to Wordpress. Yet, the situation I am in makes it difficult for me to find a solution. I have written a plugin, and I want this plugin to be imported into Wordpress so I can use it for my website.

I have zipped the file, and I have also read similar StackOverflow questions. Some used cPanel or Go Daddy (both I do not use) to solve their problem. Others changed setting in their php.ini file. I cannot find my php.ini file because I use Debian. I also tried phpinfo() in my editor to see where my php.ini is located, but with no result. I have also tried working in an incognito browser, but with no result. I am stuck and I do not know what to do.

My expectations are that I could change the settings in my php.ini to make it work. But unfortunately, I cannot find it. I am expecting to find a solution to finally be able to upload my plugin.

Greetings,

Parsa_237

Comment: Can you upload your plugin folder via FTP to your server?

Comment: No, I have tried that. I had to give a username and password and website name. But nothing worked. Do you know how to use FTP in this case?

Comment: Basically, FTP needs to be enabled on server to use it.

Comment: Ok, I will try this and come back to you in a minute

Comment: Hello, the question is not off-topic. It is a question about Wordpress. So your argument is unreasonable. I will unfortunately flag your comment so that it gets moderator attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try command line on debian

php --ini

Comment: @Parsa_237 YOUR WELCOME MAN